# memory_profiler while using lambda expression to connect slots

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyqt5, memory-profiling

I am experimenting  memory_profiler in Python3 following

https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/hunting-for-memory-leaks-in-python-applications-6824d0518774

thanks to @eyllanesc here [PyQt5 designer gui and iterate/loop over QPushButton [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643345/pyqt5-designer-gui-and-iterate-loop-over-qpushbutton?noredirect=1#comment109039766_61643345)

I just created a mainwindow with 21 buttons a to z ; each time a press one of them I print the letter they represent.

While reading: [Using lambda expression to connect slots in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819538/using-lambda-expression-to-connect-slots-in-pyqt) I came across:

" Beware! As soon as you connect your signal to a lambda slot with a reference to self, your widget will not be garbage-collected! That's because lambda creates a closure with yet another uncollectable reference to the widget.

Thus, self.someUIwidget.someSignal.connect(lambda p: self.someMethod(p)) is very evil :) "

Here my plot: [image: memory_profiler plot while pressing buttons]

while pressing buttons.

Does my plot shows this behaviour ?? Or is it a straight line that doent looks straight ?

What is an alternative then? to my:

```
use for letter in "ABCDE": getattr(self, letter).clicked.connect(lambda checked, letter=letter: foo(letter))
```

main.py : hangman_pyqt5-muppy.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue May  5 19:21:27 2020

@author: Pietro

"""

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget

import hangman005

#from pympler import muppy, summary #########################################
#
#from pympler import tracker

#import resource


WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

wordlist = hangman005.load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)



def main():


    def center(self):                     
        qr = self.frameGeometry()   
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()    
        qr.moveCenter(cp)    
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


    class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


        def __init__(self):        
            super(MainMenu, self).__init__()            
            uic.loadUi('main_window2.ui', self)                       
#                self.ButtonQ.clicked.connect(self.QPushButtonQPressed)             
            self.centro = center(self)             
            self.centro                      
#            self.show() 
            self.hangman()



        def closeEvent(self, event): #Your desired functionality here         
            close = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                         "QUIT",
                                         "Are you sure want to stop process?",
                                         QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
            if close == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()

        def printo(self, i):
            print('oooooooooooooooooooooo :', i)   
#            all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
#            sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)# Prints out a summary of the large objects
#            summary.print_(sum1) from pympler import tracker
#           
#
#            self.memory_tracker = tracker.SummaryTracker()
#            self.memory_tracker.print_diff()

        def hangman(self):
            letters_guessed=[]
            max_guesses = 6
            secret_word = hangman005.choose_word(wordlist)
            secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
            secret_word=hangman005.splitt(secret_word)
            vowels=('a','e','i','o','u')
            secret_word_print=('_ '*secret_word_lenght )
            self.word_to_guess.setText(secret_word_print )
            letters=hangman005.splitt('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYVWXXYZ')
            print(letters )
            for i in letters:
                print('lllllllllllllll : ' ,i)
#                 button = "self.MainMenu."+i
#                 self.[i].clicked.connect(self.printo(i))
#                 button = getattr(self, i)
#                button.clicked.connect((lambda : self.printo(i for i in letters) )    )
#                 button.clicked.connect(lambda j=self.printo(i) : j )
#                 button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.printo(i))
#                button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printo(i))
#            button.clicked.connect(lambda j=self.printo(i) : j   for i in letters )
#                 getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(lambda checked, i=i: self.printo(i))
#                 getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(lambda checked, j=i: self.printo(j))
                getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(lambda pippo, j=i: self.printo(j))
#            self.A.clicked.connect(self.printo)
# Add to leaky code within python_script_being_profiled.py

                 # Get references to certain types of objects such as dataframe
#                dataframes = [ao for ao in all_objects if isinstance(ao, pd.DataFrame)]
#                
#                for d in dataframes:
#                    print (d.columns.values)
#                    print (len(d))                







    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    sshFile="coffee.qss"
#    with open(sshFile,"r") as fh:
#        app.setStyleSheet(fh.read())

    window=MainMenu()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()

#all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
#sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)# Prints out a summary of the large objects
#summary.print_(sum1)# Get references to certain types of objects such as dataframe

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hangman005.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr 29 19:36:32 2020

@author: Pietro
"""



import random
import string



#WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"


def load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME):
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = line.split()
    print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
#    print(line)
#    for elem in line:
#        print (elem)
#    print(wordlist)
#    for elem in wordlist:
#        print ('\n' , elem) 
    return wordlist



def choose_word(wordlist):
    """
    wordlist (list): list of words (strings)

    Returns a word from wordlist at random
    """
    return random.choice(wordlist)

# end of helper code

# -----------------------------------

# Load the list of words into the variable wordlist
# so that it can be accessed from anywhere in the program

#wordlist = load_words()



def splitt(word): 
    return [char for char in word]   


def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing; assumes all letters are
      lowercase
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far;
      assumes that all letters are lowercase
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secret_word are in letters_guessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    prova =all(item in letters_guessed for item in secret_word )    
    print(' prova : ' , prova )
    return prova 

#secret_word='popoli'
#letters_guessed=['p','o','p','o','l','i']
#letters_guessed=['p','i','l']    
#print('\n\nis_word_guessed : ', is_word_guessed(secret_word,letters_guessed))
#letters_guessed = []


def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters, underscores (_), and spaces that represents
      which letters in secret_word have been guessed so far.
    '''
    print('\n\nsecret_word_split' , secret_word)
    print('letters_guessed', letters_guessed )
    results=[]
    for val in range(0,len(secret_word)):
            if secret_word[val] in letters_guessed:
                results.append(secret_word[val])
            else:
                results.append('_')
    print('\nresults : ' , ' '.join(results ))        
    return results


def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    '''secret_word_split
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string (of letters), comprised of letters that represents which letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    entire_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    entire_letters_split=splitt(entire_letters)
    entire_letters_split = [x for x in entire_letters_split if x not in letters_guessed]
    return entire_letters_split




def hangman(secret_word):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the secret word to guess.

    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    * At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
      letters the secret_word contains and how many guesses s/he starts with.

    * The user should start with 6 guesses

    * Before each round, you should display to the user how many guesses
      s/he has left and the letters that the user has not yet guessed.

    * Ask the user to supply one guess per round. Remember to make
      sure that the user puts in a letter!

    * The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess 
      about whether their guess appears in the computer's word.

    * After each guess, you should display to the user the 
      partially guessed word so far.
    secret_word_split
    Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
    '''

    letters_guessed=[]
    max_guesses = 6
    secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
    secret_word=splitt(secret_word)
    vowels=('a','e','i','o','u')

    print('\nWelcome to HANGMAN ;-) ')
    print('\nsecret_word_lenght : ' , secret_word_lenght  ) 
    print('\n'+' _ '*secret_word_lenght )
    print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

    while True:
        guess= input('\nmake your first choice : ' )
        if guess not in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                print('You can only choose in' , ' '.join(get_available_letters(letters_guessed)))
                continue
        if guess in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
#                print('\nletters_guessed appended : ' , ' '.join(letters_guessed) )
#                max_guesses -= 1
                print(' a che punto sei : ' , ' '.join(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed)))
#                print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                if guess in secret_word:
                    print('GOOD !!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    print('\nyou still have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                else:
                    print('ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    if guess in vowels:
                        max_guesses -= 2
                    else:
                        max_guesses -= 1
                    print('\nnow you have only' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

        if is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed) == True:
            print('\nHAI VINTO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            total_score= max_guesses * len(list(set(secret_word)))

            print('\nil tuo punteggio è : ' , total_score)

            break
        if max_guesses <= 0:
            print('\nHAI PERSO STUPIDA CAPRA !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            print('\nla parola era : ' , ''.join(secret_word), ' you moron !!')
            break




# When you've completed your hangman function, scroll down to the bottom
# of the file and uncomment the first two lines to test
#(hint: you might want to pick your own
# secret_word while you're doing your own testing)


# -----------------------------------



def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
    '''
    my_word: string with _ characters, current guess of secret word
    other_word: string, regular English word
    returns: boolean, True if all the actual letters of my_word match the 
        corresponding letters of other_word, or the letter is the special symbol
        _ , and my_word and other_word are of the same length;
        False otherwise: 
    '''

    if len(my_word) == len(other_word):

        for val in range(0,len(my_word)):
            if my_word[val] == '_':
#                print('OK')
                prova=True
            elif my_word[val] != '_' and my_word[val]==other_word[val]:
#                print('OK')
                prova=True
            else:
#                print('KO')
                prova=False
                break
    else:
#        print('DIFFERENT LENGHT')
        prova=False
    return prova


def show_possible_matches(my_word):
    '''
    my_word: string with _ characters, current guess of secret word
    returns: nothing, but should print out every word in wordlist that matches my_word
             Keep in mind that in hangman when a letter is guessed, all the positions
             at which that letter occurs in the secret word are revealed.
             Therefore, the hidden letter(_ ) cannot be one of the letters in the word
             that has already been revealed.

    '''
    x=0
    y=0
    for i in range(0,len(wordlist)):
        other_word=splitt(wordlist[i])
        if match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
            print(wordlist[i], end = ' ')
            x += 1
        else:
            y += 1
    print('\nparole trovate : ' , x)
    print('parole saltate : ' , y)
    print('parole totali  : ' , x+y)
    print('lenght wordlist :' , len(wordlist))
    return


end = ''
def hangman_with_hints(secret_word):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the secret word to guess.

    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    * At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
      letters the secret_word contains and how many guesses s/he starts with.

    * The user should start with 6 guesses
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE AND DELETE "pass"
    pass
    * Before each round, you should str display to the user how many guesses
      s/he has left and the letters that the user has not yet guessed.

    * Ask the user to supply one guess per round. Make sure to check that the user guesses a letter

    * The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess 
      about whether their guess appears in the computer's word.

    * After each guess, you should display to the user the 
      partially guessed word so far.

    * If the guess is the symbol *, print out all words in wordlist that
      matches the current guessed word. 

    Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
    '''

#    secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
#    print('secret_word_lenght : ' , secret_word_lenght  )

    letters_guessed=[]
    max_guesses = 6
    secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
    secret_word=splitt(secret_word)
    vowels=('a','e','i','o','u')

    print('\nWelcome to HANGMAN ;-) ')
    print('\nsecret_word_lenght : ' , secret_word_lenght  ) 
    print('\n use * for superhelp !!!! ')
    print('\n'+' _ '*secret_word_lenght )
    print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

    while True:
        guess= input('\nmake your choice : ' )
        if guess == '*' :
                print('ATTENZIONE SUPER BONUS !!!')
                my_word=(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
                show_possible_matches(my_word)
                continue
        if guess not in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                print('You can only choose in' , ' '.join(get_available_letters(letters_guessed)))
                continue
        if guess in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
#                print('\nletters_guessed appended : ' , ' '.join(letters_guessed) )
#                max_guesses -= 1
                print(' a che punto sei : ' , ' '.join(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed)))
#                print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                if guess in secret_word:
                    print('GOOD !!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    print('\nyou still have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                else:
                    print('ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    if guess in vowels:
                        max_guesses -= 2
                    else:
                        max_guesses -= 1
                    print('\nnow you have only' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

        if is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed) == True:
            print('\nHAI VINTO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            total_score= max_guesses * len(list(set(secret_word)))

            print('\nil tuo punteggio è : ' , total_score)

            break
        if max_guesses <= 0:
            print('\nHAI PERSO STUPIDA CAPRA !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            print('\nla parola era : ' , ''.join(secret_word).upper(), ' you moron !!')
            break

# When you've completed your hangman_with_hint function, comment the two similar
# lines above that were used to run the hangman function, and then uncomment
# these two lines and run this file to test!
# Hint: You might want to pick your own secret_word while you're testing.


#if __name__ == "__main__":
    # passui

    # To test part 2, comment out the pass line above and
    # uncomment the following two lines.

#    secret_word = choose_word(wordlist)
#    hangman(secret_word)

###############

    # To test part 3 re-comment out the above lines and 
    # uncomment the following two lines. 

#    secret_word = choose_word(wordlist)
#    hangman_with_hints(secret_word)
```

ui file, main_window2.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>863</width>
    <height>687</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>HANGMAN</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="word_to_guess">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>250</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>341</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>18</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>word_to_guess</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>821</width>
      <height>201</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
    background-color: #9de650;
}


QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: green;
}

</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="A">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="autoFillBackground">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>A</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="B">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>90</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>B</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="C">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>150</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>C</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="D">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>210</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>D</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="E">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>270</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>E</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="F">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>330</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>F</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="G">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>390</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>G</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="H">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>450</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>H</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="I">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>510</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>I</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="J">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>570</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>J</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="K">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>630</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>K</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="L">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>690</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>L</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="M">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>750</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>M</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="N">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>N</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="O">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>90</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>O</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="P">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>150</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>P</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Q">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>210</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Q</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="R">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>270</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>R</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="S">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>330</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>S</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="T">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>390</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>T</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="U">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>450</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>U</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="V">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>510</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>V</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="W">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>570</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>W</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="X">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>630</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>X</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Y">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>690</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Y</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Z">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>750</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Z</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>863</width>
     <height>29</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar">
   <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

words.txt :

```
 sinew sings singe sinks sinus sioux sires sired siren sisal sissy sitar sites sited sixes sixty sixth sizes sized skate skeet skein skews skids skied skier skies skiff skill skims skimp skins skink skips skirl skirt skits skulk skull skunk slabs slack slags slain slake slams slang slant slaps slash slats slate slavs slave slaws slays sleds sleek sleep sleet slept slews slice slick slide slier slims slime slimy sling slink slips slits sloes slogs sloop slops slope
```

As described here:

[Using lambda expression to connect slots in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819538/using-lambda-expression-to-connect-slots-in-pyqt)

"Using slots with closures is not evil. If you're concerned about object cleanup, just explicitly disconnect any signals connected to slots forming a closure over the object being deleted. "

I dont understand any of it. How could I possibly disconnect the signals ?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: added all relevant files, not minimal really.  self.memory_tracker =tracker.SummaryTracker(), self.memory_tracker.print_diff()  lines 71-72 of main.py give +1 everytime I push a button, not sure if its a difference

Comment: Although you don't explicitly point out that I think you think you have a memory leak, what did you expect to get?

Comment: my question was about the plot : is it showing an increase in memory usage (yes/no) ? is it due to memory leak ? If Ye/Yess how could I avoid it ?

Comment: is it showing an increase in memory usage (yes/no) ?: According to the graph yes, do you want that answer?

Comment: "Using slots with closures is not evil. If you're concerned about object cleanup, just explicitly disconnect any signals connected to slots forming a closure over the object being deleted. " I dont understand any of it. How could I possibly disconnect the signals ?

Comment: In what part of your post is that ?, is the reference to the post but you explicitly do not point that out so I recommend you edit your question and add that.

Comment: Now my question is: Do you want those functions to be invoked every time the buttons are pressed or just once? Since if the function signal is disconnected then the function will not be invoked after that. I think you want to optimize your application but you do not understand that this depends on the life cycle of your application but that you do not explicitly point out.

Comment: I managed t finish the hangman assignment (ps2) of the MIT 6001 course on Python. then was trying to move it to Pyqt5, thats why I asked about the 'PyQt5 designer gui and iterate/loop over QPushButton [duplicate]'. Trying to understand lambda anc QPushButton connect I stumbled on the memory leak post so I went for it.I know its not the best way to learn things but sometimes I cant help jumping around. Every time a press a button I am choosing a letter for hangman so I should be able to use them more than once... or at least I believe

Comment: I press a button, choosing a letter, something happens, as in my windowless hangman, then I should press another button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501804/6622587) does not have to do with PyQt5 but with the lambda functions since, like any function, it creates a scope and stores memory, to test what the OP points out I have created the following example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.counter = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_timeout(self):
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter % 2 == 0:
            self.connect()
        else:
            self.disconnect()

    def connect(self):
        self.button.setText("Connected")
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda checked: None)
        # or
        # self.button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, v=list(range(100000)): None)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.button.setText("Disconnected")
        self.button.disconnect()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- `self.button.clicked.connect(lambda checked: None)`

[image]

- `self.button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, v=list(range(100000)): None)`

[image]

As observed at the time of connection and disconnection, the memory consumed increases since the lambda maintains the information of `v=list(range(100000))`.

---

But in your code the closure stores only the variable "j" which is minimum:

```py
getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(lambda pippo, j=i: self.printo(j))
```

To see how this variable affects I am going to eliminate the unnecessary code for the test (hangman005.py, etc) in addition to offering alternatives:

- without connect:

```py
class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("main_window2.ui", self)
        self.hangman()

    def hangman(self):
        letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYVWXXYZ"
        for i in letters:
            pass

    def printo(self, i):
        print("oooooooooooooooooooooo :", i)
```

[image]

- with lambda:

```py
class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("main_window2.ui", self)
        self.hangman()

    def hangman(self):
        letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYVWXXYZ"
        for i in letters:
            getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(lambda pippo, j=i: self.printo(j))

    def printo(self, i):
        print("oooooooooooooooooooooo :", i)
```

[image]

- with functools.partial

```py
class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("main_window2.ui", self)
        self.hangman()

    def hangman(self):
        letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYVWXXYZ"
        for i in letters:
            getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(partial(self.printo, i))

    def printo(self, i):
        print("oooooooooooooooooooooo :", i)
```

[image]

- once connect

```py
class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("main_window2.ui", self)
        self.hangman()

    def hangman(self):
        letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYVWXXYZ"
        for i in letters:
            getattr(self, i).setProperty("i", i)
            getattr(self, i).clicked.connect(self.printo)

    def printo(self):
        i = self.sender().property("i")
        print("oooooooooooooooooooooo :", i)
```

[image]

As we can see there is no significant difference between all the methods so in your case there is no memory leak or rather it is very small.

In conclusion: Every time you create a lambda method it has a closure (`j = i` in your case) so the OP recommends taking that into account, for example in your case `len(letters) * size_of(i)` are consumed which at Being small `letters` and `i` makes it negligible, but if you otherwise store a heavier object unnecessarily then it will cause problems

Comment: As concluded non of the alternatives prevents lambda from memory leaking. Aside from disconnecting the signal from the slot is there any other way to recover lambda's memory leak?

Comment: Looks like QWidget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) recover memory after a QWidget is close (Ex: MainWindow with SubWindows)

Comment: pyqt: A correct way to connect multiple signals to the same function in pyqt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304203/pyqt-a-correct-way-to-connect-multiple-signals-to-the-same-function-in-pyqt-qs/33310118

Comment: @Rhdr you have to understand a basic concept: PyQt implements wrappers around the Q-Class, so a QObject (Python) has the QObjec (C++) + intermediate code object, the lambda only handles the QObject (Python) so another object I could remove the QObjec (C++), just ekhumoro shows a problem with the lambda. **In my answer I focus only on whether or not there is memory leak**.

Comment: @Rhdr Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969809/pyqt5-deletelater-vs-sip-delete/61973204#61973204 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915979/is-it-safe-to-remove-a-python-reference-to-a-qt-object-directly-after-calling-de/61917622#61917622

Comment: @Rhdr Thank you for doing the research as it gives me the opportunity to write an article about the care that must be taken with the lambdas in the Qt connections.